# Does chrome store cookies from images?

Tags: javascript, html, image, google-chrome, cookies

Let's say I have a website (`https://example.com`), if I have an image on that website that is from my second website (`https://example2.com`), will Chrome store the cookies that it got from that image?

Like on the image, if I set the `Set-Cookie` header to store a cookie saying that the image was fetched, will chrome save the cookie in the browser and if I were to visit `https://example2.com`, I would be able to see that my browser had fetched an image from my servers before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these are [third-party cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#third-party_cookies) and work just as you describe. The browser will save them under the domain of the specific resource they were sent under, and re-send them on future requests to that domain, whether they are top-level page requests or sub-resource requests (e.g., an image).

The server must authorize a cookie to be sent as a third-party cookie via the [`SameSite=None`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) cookie attribute. This also requires use of the `Secure` attribute, meaning in practice that third-party cookies can only be sent over HTTPS.

Third-party cookies currently work (as of July 2021) in modern browsers, but are blocked by default in Chrome's Incognito mode:

[image: An toggle for the "Block third-party cookies" option in Incognito]

Third-party cookies are a major part of how cross-site tracking works: when any site embeds an advertisement or tracking image as a cross-site `<img>`, the foreign site serving the embedded image may send and read cookies for their domain, allowing them to know who they're serving ads for. (Have we seen this user before on any other partner sites? Do we have ads relevant to our understanding of this user's browsing habits?)

However, Google is trying to cease use of third-party cookies in advertising, so their future is somewhat uncertain.

I have a simple use of third-party cookies on my [Arqade profile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/87199/apsillers?tab=profile), which embeds a remote image from `repl.co`. The image is served with a unique cookie (and thereafter requested with that same unique cookie) to persistently control the same character in a game. There is no other communication with `repl.co` needed to establish this cookie relationship besides the embedded image.

Comment: @EniolaOyewole Thanks! You might also enjoy [the same principle used to run Doom](https://twitter.com/apsillers/status/1394653184447090691) (with explanatory video) `:D` That one doesn't need third-party cookies though.